# Firebase_auth photoURL not working. Returning default person image

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

flutter 1.20.4;
flutter_login_facebook: ^0.2.1;
firebase_auth: ^0.18.1;
firebase_core: ^0.5.0;
provider: ^4.3.2;

Display name and email is working, but photoURL returns this:
I tried to build it on different devices and tried to login to different facebook account.
https://graph.facebook.com/1757577617747458/picture

My HomeScreen

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  StreamSubscription<User> homeStateSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    var authBloc = Provider.of<AuthBloc>(context, listen: false);
    homeStateSubscription = authBloc.currentUser.listen((fbUser) {
      if (fbUser == null) {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var authBloc = Provider.of<AuthBloc>(context);
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: StreamBuilder<User>(
          stream: authBloc.currentUser,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
            print(snapshot.data.email);

            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(snapshot.data.displayName,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35.0)),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.0,
                ),
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      snapshot.data.photoURL + '?width=500&height500'),
                  radius: 60.0,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 100.0,
                ),
                SignInButton(Buttons.Facebook,
                    text: 'Sign out of Facebook',
                    onPressed: () => authBloc.logout())
              ],
            );
          }),
    ));
  }
}
```

This is Bloc

```
class AuthBloc {
  final authService = AuthService();
  final fb = FacebookLogin();

  Stream<User> get currentUser => authService.currentUser;

  loginFacebook() async {

    final res = await fb.logIn(permissions: [
      FacebookPermission.publicProfile,
      FacebookPermission.email
    ]);

    switch (res.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.Success:
        print('It worked');

        //Get Token
        final FacebookAccessToken fbToken = res.accessToken;

        //Convert to Auth Credential
        final AuthCredential credential =
            FacebookAuthProvider.credential(fbToken.token);

        //User Credential to Sign in with Firebase
        final result = await authService.signInWithCredentail(credential);

        print('${result.user.displayName} is now logged in');

        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.Cancel:
        print('The user canceled the login');
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.Error:
        print('There was an error');
        break;
    }
  }

  logout() {
    authService.logout();
  }
}
```

My Auth Service

```
class AuthService {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Stream<User> get currentUser => _auth.authStateChanges();
  Future<UserCredential> signInWithCredentail(AuthCredential credential) =>
      _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  Future<void> logout() => _auth.signOut();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. It seems that FB changed the way to get the profile picture.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

"Apps in Development mode that make tokenless requests on ASIDs will receive a silhouette image in response."

Using the token after sign in with Facebook can be used to retrieve image from graph API. The problem is that I needed to download the image and show up in profile widget.